# SQL users searching query

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I would like to create query to search given information in table `users`. Table consists: of `id`, `username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `phone` and `email`.

Sample search text: `mat h 50 @l d`

The only record that should be returned: `1 | admin | mat | hladeo | 123450789 | admin@localhost`

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE (
(`firstname` LIKE  '%mat%') || (`firstname` LIKE  '%h%') ||
(`firstname` LIKE  '%50%') || (`firstname` LIKE  '%@l%') ||
(`firstname` LIKE  '%d%')
) && (
(`lastname` LIKE  '%mat%') || (`lastname` LIKE  '%h%') ||
(`lastname` LIKE  '%50%') || (`lastname` LIKE  '%@l%') ||
(`lastname` LIKE  '%d%')
) && (
(`phone` LIKE  '%mat%') || (`phone` LIKE  '%h%' ) ||
(`phone` LIKE  '%50%') || (`phone` LIKE  '%@l%') ||
(`phone` LIKE  '%d%')
) && (
(`email` LIKE  '%mat%') || (`email` LIKE  '%h%') ||
(`email` LIKE  '%50%' ) || (`email` LIKE  '%@l%') ||
(`email` LIKE  '%d%')
) && (
(`username` LIKE  '%mat%') || (`username` LIKE  '%h%') ||
(`username` LIKE  '%50%') || (`username` LIKE  '%@l%') ||
(`username` LIKE  '%d%')
)
```

But this query is returning people who have got username containing `d` and their phone number contains `50`.

**EDIT:**
this query returns 3 rows:

```
1 | admin | mat | hladeo | 123450789 | admin@localhost
8 | dillese | Adriana | Zolch | 44450232 | dilesse@msn.com
12 | dcolhut | Denise | Colhut | 502222222 | dcolhut@msn.com
```

and should return only first row (because matches all the requirements).

==========

And the main question - how to optimize this query? Is it possible to make it simplier?

Regards

Comment: You could use a regex instead of a `LIKE` pattern: `fieldname RLIKE 'mat|h|50|@l|d'` It will still be inefficient, since this regexp has to scan all records, it can't use an index.

Comment: Why shouldn't it return people who have username containing `d` and phone containing `50`? What is the matching logic supposed to be?

Comment: I do not know how to specify it correctly in SQL, but "this query" should return only perfectly matched record, where all the information are found - not only some part of it like username containing `d` and phone containing `50`

Comment: So each part of the sample text has to match a different field, but they aren't specifying which part has to match which field, and you want all fields to be matched?

Comment: Could you give an example of a record that it returns that shouldn't? I'm still not sure I get it.

Comment: `8 | dillese | Adriana | Zolch | 44450232 | dilesse@msn.com`  
  `12 | dcolhut | Denise | Colhut | 502222222 | dcolhut@msn.com`
@offtopic: is it possible to break line in comment?

Comment: No, there's very little formatting in comments. It would be best if you edited it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE (
       (firstname LIKE '%mat%' OR lastname LIKE '%mat%' OR
        phone LIKE '%mat%' OR email LIKE '%mat%' OR username LIKE '%mat%')
       AND
       (firstname LIKE '%h%' OR lastname LIKE '%h%' OR
        phone LIKE '%h%' OR email LIKE '%h%' OR username LIKE '%h%')
       AND
       (firstname LIKE '%50%' OR lastname LIKE '%50%' OR
        phone LIKE '%50%' OR email LIKE '%50%' OR username LIKE '%50%')
       AND
       (firstname LIKE '%@l%' OR lastname LIKE '%@l%' OR
        phone LIKE '%@l%' OR email LIKE '%@l%' OR username LIKE '%@l%')
       AND
       (firstname LIKE '%d%' OR lastname LIKE '%d%' OR
        phone LIKE '%d%' OR email LIKE '%d%' OR username LIKE '%d%')
      )
```

You need to test each criteria separately, not each field.

Comment: It looks that it works. But I will do some more tests. If they pass, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: It looks that everything is correct. Thank you very much for help :)