# Incorrect PDO result using loop

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, string, pdo

Connected with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785418/sql-users-searching-query)

I have got a really strange problem. When I use hardcoded values to retrieve data from arrays and pass as parameter to PDO, than everything is fine. Problems become when I am trying to use any loop - than the result is wrong.

this code works correctly:

```
$tokenNo = 0;
$searchTokens = preg_split("/\s+/", $search_string);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ( (firstname LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR
lastname LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR phone LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR
email LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR username LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . ")";

for ($tokenNo=1; $tokenNo < count($searchTokens); $tokenNo++) { 
  $sql .= " AND (firstname LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . 
  " OR lastname LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR phone LIKE :token" . $tokenNo .
  " OR email LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR username LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . ")";
}
$sql .= " )";


if($query = $this->db->prepare($sql)) {
  $tokenNo = 0;
  $str1 = "%" . $searchTokens[$tokenNo] . "%";
  $query->bindParam(':token' . $tokenNo, $str1);

  $tokenNo = 1;
  $str2 = "%" . $searchTokens[$tokenNo] . "%";
  $query->bindParam(':token' . $tokenNo, $str2);

  $query->execute();

  $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  var_dump($rows);
}
```

but this not:

```
$tokenNo = 0;
$searchTokens = preg_split("/\s+/", $search_string);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ( (firstname LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR
lastname LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR phone LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR
email LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR username LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . ")";

for ($tokenNo=1; $tokenNo < count($searchTokens); $tokenNo++) { 
  $sql .= " AND (firstname LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . 
  " OR lastname LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR phone LIKE :token" . $tokenNo .
  " OR email LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . " OR username LIKE :token" . $tokenNo . ")";
}
$sql .= " )";


if($query = $this->db->prepare($sql)) {
  $tokenNo = 0;

  while( $tokenNo < count(searchTokens) ) {
    $str1 = "%" . $searchTokens[$tokenNo] . "%";
    $query->bindParam(':token' . $tokenNo, $str1);
    $tokenNo++;
  }

  $query->execute();

  $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  var_dump($rows);
}
```

the same is happening if I use `for` loop.

The wrong result is showing too much data - issue from [connected question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785418/sql-users-searching-query)

Regards

Comment: you have a typo: `$tokensNo` to `$tokenNo`?

Comment: $tokenNo sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Bind Param Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) given parameter must be reference...

Easiest solution that comes to my mind is make array of strings:

```
while( $tokenNo < count(searchTokens) ) {
  $str[$tokenNo] = "%" . $searchTokens[$tokenNo] . "%";
  $query->bindParam(':token' . $tokenNo, $str[$tokenNo]);
  $tokenNo++;
}
```

And now it works...